# ANY SQL Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types

Tags: sql, database, table-relationships

Hi I've searched the web and this site for the answer I'm looking for but the answers aren't helping me in my case.

I'm making a database for a shop that has multiple locations. Everything worked until I normalized the database. As you can see here:

```
create table Locatie (

locatie integer,
adres varchar (70),
plaats varchar (70) not null,


constraint pk_locatie primary key (locatie)); go


create table Voorraad (

artikelnr integer,
voorraadid integer,
aantal integer not null,
locatie integer not null,

constraint pk_artikelnr_aantal primary key (artikelnr, aantal),
constraint fk_Artikel_Voorraad foreign key (artikelnr) references Artikel (artikelnr),
constraint fk_Locatie_Voorraad foreign key (voorraadid) references Locatie (locatie),

constraint uq_voorraadid_locatie unique (voorraadid, locatie)); go
```

these are ofcourse my parrent tables. But I get the error in the child one:

```
create table Artikelvoorraad (
artikelnr integer,
voorraadid integer,
aantal integer not null,

constraint pk_artikelnr_voorraadid primary key (artikelnr, voorraadid),
constraint fk_Artikel_Artikelvoorraad foreign key (artikelnr) 
references Artikel (artikelnr),
constraint fk_Voorraad_Artikelvoorraad foreign key (voorraadid) 
references Voorraad (voorraadid, locatie)); go
```

Is there someone who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this one

```
...
constraint fk_Voorraad_Artikelvoorraad foreign key (voorraadid) 
references Voorraad (voorraadid, locatie)
...
```

You see that you try to reference one field from table `Artikelvoorraad` to two fields in the table `Voorraad`. You probably want to change it to

```
...
constraint fk_Voorraad_Artikelvoorraad foreign key (voorraadid) 
references Voorraad (voorraadid)
...
```

But again, your table `Voorraad` has a strange primary key - why amount is also in the key? If the key is correct, then probably you want this:

```
constraint fk_Voorraad_Artikelvoorraad foreign key (voorraadid, aantal) 
references Voorraad (voorraadid, aantal)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But Voorraad has a unique key and by combining it I thought to solve it. Only now I got a problem I had before this error

Comment: No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table. So that is why I combined the two.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I've put amount in the primary key because the amount is every time different from the other stores. But now I see a problem with that yes. If amount would be 21 at a certain time. It can never be 21 again. Well I'm still back at where I began. But thank you for your help!